# Overview: Tenant isolation in current DaaS offerings?

Tags: azure-sql-database, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql, amazon-simpledb

I am interested in tenant isolation in current database-as-a-service offerings. How is multi-tenancy implemented by DaaS providers? Do they isolate data of their tenants by isolating VMs, DBMSs, databases, schemas or tables? Or do they use a shared table approach like Salesforce? Do you know some material (websites or publications) for
Microsoft Azure SQL Database, Amazon RDS/DynamoDB/SimpleDB, or Google Cloud SQL? Please let me know.
With kind regards

Comment: thank you, Chris. Do you have a link with these informations?

Comment: SQL Azure previously had federations which allowed isolation by having different databases, but now they have no preferred method. Build it yourself.

Comment: For Google CloudSQL, instances are not shared between users.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) – Amazon SimpleDB can be useful for those who need a non-relational database for storage of smaller, non-structural data. Amazon SimpleDB has restricted storage size to 10GB per domain and it can achieve up to 25 writes/second. Amazon SimpleDB offers simplicity and flexibility. SimpleDB automatically indexes all data. Amazon SimpleDB pricing is based on your actual box usage. You can store any UTF-8 string data in Amazon SimpleDB.

[Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/simpledb/), [Third party Tool](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/)

[Amazon DynamoDB service](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) – Amazon DynamoDB can be useful for those who need a fast, highly scalable non-relational database. There is no limit on the storage size per table and you can specify how much request capability you require. Amazon DynamoDB offers good performance and incremental scalability. DynamoDB indexes only the primary key, which can be a composite primary key. DynamoDB is priced according to how much request capacity you have requested. You can store Strings and Numbers.

[Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/dynamodb/)